# Getting width of component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve the width of my component using @rehooks/component-size which is meant to look something like this:

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import useComponentSize from '@rehooks/component-size'

function MyComponent() {
  let ref = useRef(null)
  let { width } = useComponentSize(ref)
```

It worked for me before a refactor but now it just provides 0.
I'm trying to get the width of a linechart

```
      <div className={styles.timeline}>
        <Plot
          {...baseChartSettings}
          data={[{ x: time, y: groundSpeedData }]}
          layout={{
            xaxis: {
              range: filters.byTime,
              rangeslider: {
                range: [0, data.maxTime],
              },
            },
          }}
          onUpdate={(
            {
              layout: {
                xaxis: { range },
              },
            }: any // Figure, with 100% defined xaxis and yaxis atts
          ) => {
            if (anyChangeInRange(filters.byTime, range)) {
              filters.byTime = range;
              setFilter({ ...filter });
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

edit: adding ref={ref} to the `<div className={styles.timeline}>` is what I was missing

Comment: I don't see any ref on your linechart component, I suppose you should provide it

Comment: ok yeah sweet just notice that the version before refactoring had `<div className="root" ref={ref}>` which hopefully is what I'm missing here

Comment: @Konstantin yeah cheers that was it, didn't write that part of the code the first time so didn't even think to look at that